# SciChart NumericAxis3D Set MajorTickLineStyle TickLength Error

Tags: wpf, scichart

I am seting MajorTickLineStyle for NumericAxis3D  ,I set the TickLength,but result
tickLength error.please the picture.
this is my code:

```
 <Style x:Key="MajorTickLineStyle" TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Y2" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="X2" Value="20"/>
        </Style>
```

[image]

Comment: I used MajorTickLineStyle to set the X-axis tick line style, but the length of the tick mark display is not correct, the specific effect please look at the picture. Can you take a look at it for me? Thank you!

Comment: <s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>
                <s3D:NumericAxis3D TickTextBrush="Red"  x:Name="XAxis"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   FontWeight="Bold"
                                   TickLabelAlignment="ScreenAutoRotated"
                                   MajorTickLineStyle="{StaticResource MajorTickLineStyle}" />
            </s3D:SciChart3DSurface.XAxis>

Comment: @Downvoters, give the guy a chance will you? It's their first post ever. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users